# OData Library Edm.Internal.Cache null reference exception

Tags: odata, ado.net-entity-data-model

We are using the October 2011 CTP of the Microsoft OData library. For some time, including previous versions, we have been encountering an intermittent null reference exception upon model serialization from deep in the internals of the library.

> System.NullReferenceException
>
> at Microsoft.Data.Edm.Internal.Cache`2.GetValue(TContainer container,
>   Func`2 compute, Func`2 onCycle)
>
> at
>   Microsoft.Data.Edm.Csdl.Internal.CsdlSemantics.CsdlSemanticsStructuredTypeDefinition.FindProperty(String
>   name)
>
> at Microsoft.Data.OData.ValidationUtils.ValidatePropertyDefined(String
>   propertyName, IEdmStructuredType owningStructuredType)
>
> at
>   Microsoft.Data.OData.Json.ODataJsonWriterUtils.WriteProperty(JsonWriter
>   jsonWriter, IODataUrlResolver urlResolver, IEdmModel model,
>   ODataProperty property, IEdmStructuredType owningType, Boolean
>   allowNamedStreamProperty, Uri baseUriForNamedStreamProperty,
>   ODataVersion version, DuplicatePropertyNamesChecker
>   duplicatePropertyNamesChecker, ProjectedPropertiesAnnotation
>   projectedProperties, Boolean writingResponse, ODataWriterBehavior
>   writerBehavior)
>
> at
>   Microsoft.Data.OData.Json.ODataJsonWriterUtils.WriteProperties(JsonWriter
>   jsonWriter, IODataUrlResolver urlResolver, IEdmModel model,
>   IEdmStructuredType owningType, IEnumerable`1 properties, Boolean
>   allowNamedStreamProperty, Uri baseUriForNamedStreamProperty,
>   ODataVersion version, DuplicatePropertyNamesChecker
>   duplicatePropertyNamesChecker, ProjectedPropertiesAnnotation
>   projectedProperties, Boolean writingResponse, ODataWriterBehavior
>   writerBehavior)
>
> at Microsoft.Data.OData.Json.ODataJsonWriter.EndEntry(ODataEntry
>   entry)
>
> at
>   Microsoft.Data.OData.ODataWriterCore.b__18()
>
> at Microsoft.Data.OData.ODataWriterCore.InterceptException(Action
>   action)
>
> at Microsoft.Data.OData.ODataWriterCore.WriteEndImplementation()
>
> at Microsoft.Data.OData.ODataWriterCore.WriteEnd()

We have implemented a workaround (explicit pre-initialization of the EDM by calling IEdmModel.Validate(...)) that initially seemed to prevent the failure, but this is not consistently effective.

Is anyone else seeing this problem and if so is there an effective workaround/solution?

Thanks,

Eric

Answer (score 1):

I assume this happens for you when you use the same IEdmModel from multiple threads at the same time, right? (if not please let me know, since that would be a bug which we are not aware of).

This is a know bug in the CTP which we fixed already and will be fixed in the RTM release.

The only workaround I can think of is to not use the same model from multiple threads at the same time (for now).

Comment: It is possible that this is occurring on concurrent requests. Even though we see it on a single page load on an isolated server, the page loads make concurrent AJAX requests. The problem is not frequently reproduced, so it may be hard to say for sure - but we can try placing the metadata on a per thread lifetime manager and see how that holds up.